# How to show 0 as blank in JS Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

I have a table in Tabulator and would like to show all 0 values in the cells as blank. What's the best way to achieve this?

My first attempt was to write a custom mutator:

```
mutator: function(value, data, type, params, component){
   if (value == 0){
      return "";
   }
   else{
      return value;
   }
}
```

This works but feels wrong. Further, I would like to create calculated fields on top of this and this doesn't work properly with the blank strings. Then I need to re-convert them back to zeroes in the next function.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function that returns a copy of the original `array` but with all 0 values in the cells as blank then you display it, and each time you need to calculate or update you do it based on/in the original one then you always display the copy

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [cell formatter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/format#format). A mutator will change the data but I don't think you want this - you just want to change the display of the data.

See my [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/shunty/pen/oNyxQLv) and take a look at the `moneyColFormatter` function.

Specifically, in the cell definition:

```
  ...
  formatter: (cell) => this.moneyColFormatter(cell),
```

and then implement it somehow

```
  private moneyColFormatter(cell): string {
    // If we want to show 0 values as blank:
    if (!cell.getValue()) {
      return "";
    }
    return cell.getValue();
  }
```

The Codepen also contains aggregated functions, calculated cols and custom dynamic columns.